# How can I use all of my Exact Online divisions with Invantive Bridge and PowerBI?

Tags: exact-online, microsoft-powerbi, invantive-sql, invantive-bridge

I'm using the Invantive Bridge ADO.NET provider to get my Exact Online data into Microsoft PowerBI.

This is the query I currently use:

```
let
    Source = AdoDotNet.Query
             ( "Invantive"
             , "provider=ExactOnlineAll;apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.nl;"
             , "select * from exactonlinerest..journals"
             )
in
    Source
```

This gives me the data from the default selected division in Exact Online. I would however like to be able to query not just the default division, but a selection or all of my divisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either select all divisions or a selection of your divisions in your query as following:

### Use all

```
let
    Source = AdoDotNet.Query
             ( "Invantive"
             , "provider=ExactOnlineAll;apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.nl;"
             , "use all;select * from exactonlinerest..journals"
             )
in
    Source
```

Which will look like this in the Advanced Editor:

[image: Use all divisions]

---

### Use a selection of divisions

```
let
    Source = AdoDotNet.Query
             ( "Invantive"
             , "provider=ExactOnlineAll;apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.nl;"
             , "use 823645, 103786, 878904;select * from exactonlinerest..journals"
             )
in
    Source
```

Which will look like this in the Advanced Editor:

[image: Use a selection of divisions]

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Custom Connectors (see), you can not easily edit the query. In that case you can specify the SQL statements upon connection establishment to set the right companies as shown in picture below: 
[image: specify SQL upon connect to Exact Online from Power BI]

Brute force is

```
use all
```

When you run for an accountant with thousands of companies, that might take a while :-)

To select some companies, comma-separated:

```
use 123123, 2342343
```

To select all companies with a specific name:

```
use select code from systemdivisions where name like '%Albert Heijn%'
```